# the notes of my rhythm game are not spawned at the exact time they need to

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a rhythm game for a university project and I'm using a midi file to spawn the notes. Before the song stars, the game interprets the notes in the file as notes for the game and assigns them a "time of occurence", being that the exact time a precise note should be pressed in the game to be in sync with the song. Every note spawns X seconds before this time of occurence and travels in X seconds to the control point where the player should press the note. This should work in paper, but in reality almost all the notes spawn with a random micro-delay and the game feels sloppy as a result. In addition to this, the first notes spawn way before their occurrence, with no relation to the actual song.

I tried to look for an alternate way of implementing the spawn of the notes without using the Update method and to make the spawn bound to the exact time instead of the framerate, but I really didn't find any solution being this my very first unity project.

I have 3 scripts directly involved in this part of the project, them being Note, Lane and SongManager.

These methods are from SongManager:

public void ReadFromFile()  //reads the file
{
midiFile = MidiFile.Read(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + midiLocation); //finds the midi file path
GetDataFromMidi();
}

```
public void GetDataFromMidi() //takes the data from the file
{
    var notes = midiFile.GetNotes();
    var array = new Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Interaction.Note[notes.Count];
    notes.CopyTo(array, 0);

    foreach (var lane in lanes) lane.SetTimeStamps(array); //for every lane, it inserts the correct notes

    Invoke(nameof(StartSong), songDelayInSeconds);
}

public static double GetAudioSourceTime()
{
    return (double)Instance.audioSource.timeSamples / Instance.audioSource.clip.frequency;
}
```

These methods are from Lane:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    timePassing = SongManager.GetAudioSourceTime();


    if (spawnIndex < timeStamps.Count) //if there are notes to be spawned...
    {
        timeSpawn = timeStamps[spawnIndex] - SongManager.Instance.noteSpeed / 2;
   
        if (timePassing >= timeSpawn) //if the atual time is equal or major to the time the note occurs...
        {
            Instantiate(notePrefab); //it spawns the note
            spawnIndex++; 
        }
    }
}

public void SetTimeStamps(Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Interaction.Note[] array) //reads the notes of the song and saves in this lane the correct notes
{
    foreach (var note in array)
    {
        if (note.NoteName == noteRestriction)
        {
            var metricTimeSpan = TimeConverter.ConvertTo<MetricTimeSpan>(note.Time, SongManager.midiFile.GetTempoMap()); 
            timeStamps.Add((double)metricTimeSpan.Minutes * 60f + metricTimeSpan.Seconds + (double)metricTimeSpan.Milliseconds / 1000f); 

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think the real problem is how you move these notes

Comment: I think the real issue here is the use of FixedUpdate.  Why use FixedUpdate?  It is meant for doing work with physics.  It runs at a fixed interval which is likely slower than you need.  Change that to Update.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the main reason for your micro-lag is the `Instantiate` call. Especially if you are playing the same notes every time. It is much more reasonable to load all the sounds before the song starts and just play them when it is needed.

So, instead of instantiating each note prefab, load all the notes once and then play the needed one.

Comment: Or pool "enough" note object instances and show and hide on demand.

Comment: I think I may have explained myself wrong, but the note in the game is not the sound of the note but the round object that moves from the top of the screen to the bottom and that the player needs to tap. Anyway, the suggestion of loading all the notes at the beginning of the level and having all of them come down one by one is a good one, I'll try and see if I find a way of implementing it.

Comment: If you need to move note objects, you should also consider @AKX comment. You can load notes object, then remove them in the pool instead of destroying for further reuse. I

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want notes that move in some way, with a line representing "Now". Do not spawn notes at a fixed place and speed.

Use a [audioSource.Time](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-time.html) to give you the current playback time and compute the position of the notes directly

```
var timeRemaining = note.Time - audioSource.Time;
var position = timeRemaining / noteSpeed;
```